# IntelliJ(WebStorm) Mongo Explorer doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm trying to use [Mongo Explorer plugin](https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea) on WebStorm, but it doesn't work. I added mongo executable pass and server's path from Preferences dialog. It shows the server, but it doesn't show the contents below the server. Why?

[image]

Comment: I followed exact same way of this video. http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/06/mean-stack-walkthrough-and-tips/

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin doesn't work in WebStorm 9 because it has some internal change. You have to use a previous version of WebStorm if you want to use the plugin.

https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/100

Answer (score 3):

Seems the plugin is not compatible with WebStorm version you are using. I'd suggest logging a bug in plugin issue tracker(https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues), providing your idea.log